# Paypal IPN firing failed even if URL is accessible from internet?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have set an IPN notification URL in paypal website. When I checked the IPN history in my merchant account, it shows the attempt failed. Also I logged the first line of my notification method . But there is no log for the method trigger.
What might be the posssible reason for this.

I  also tried checking the URL with IPN simulater , but it says 
**"We're sorry, we could not connect to this URL. Please make sure it was entered correctly."**

And most annoyingly paypal customer support is responding to my ticket very slowly. Please help.

Comment: how can you be sure the url is accessible via internet? Paypal does not lie

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get through to paypal technical services, they would tell you the same thing: PayPal can't connect to your listener. I'd recommend checking the listener from outside of your own network environment and making sure it responds with a http 200.

Comment: I checked the URL from outside my network, it is working and I got the logs that it is triggered. But I am not getting any logs after my transaction via paypal with IPN enable to that URL.

Comment: Could you provide the URL?